# Hibernate JOIN Query

Tags: java, hibernate

This is probably very simple and I'm just missing something but I have two classes

```
Event {
  String codeword;
  int id;
}
```

And

```
Person {
   String codeword;
}
```

Now I would like to get `List<Int> idList` which has all of the `id's` of Events where `event.codeword=person.codeword`.

In Hibernate I would like to have the line:

```
List idList = session.createQuery("Select a.id From Event a Join Person b On a.codeword=b.codeword").list().
```

However, I'm getting an association error. I don't have such an Object as IDList to actually map to.

So, I tried doing `List eventList = ("Select a From Event a ... ")`

But, that also gives me a mapping error.

How do I do such a join?

Comment: select event.id from Event event, Person person where event.codeword = person.codeword

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve this by using `getSession().createSQLQuery` instead of `getSession().createQuery()` you've been used, because `createQuery` works with hibernate entities and needs to be mapped correctly.

BUT

Suggest you to use relational objects in better way and use the `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` to handle these associations.

Therefore you can try defining entities like this:

```
Event {
  @ManyToOne
  Person codeword;
  int id;
}
```

and

```
Person {
   String codeword;
}
```

after that depending which hibernate API (Criteria, HQL, JPQL, ...) you used for getting data,
you can call `event.getPerson()` and so on.